# loader for app.json published from editor

Tags: json, three.js

I published a ready-textured model using the editor and then tried to load it with the JSONLoader. whatever i´m trying to resolve that issue (tried the ObjectLoader) - it seems I´m missing an important thing: the model just won´t show up.

```
<body ontouchstart="">
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JSONLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PerspectiveCamera.js"></script>

    <script>




width=window.innerWidth;
height=window.innerHeight;
start();
animate();

function start(){

    camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,width/height,1,10000);
    camera.position.set(0,0,-80);
    control=new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
    control.addEventListener("change",render);
    scene=new THREE.Scene();


    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'app.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    loader.onLoadComplete=function(){scene.add( mesh )}
    });




    renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0xaaaaaa);
    renderer.setSize(width,height);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);



}
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    control.update();
}
function render(){
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

    </script>
</body>
```

I guess this is pretty messy copy&paste&trial&error you´re looking at.
[This is the app.json-file.](http://postproduct.de/threejs/app_json.zip)
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `loader.onLoadComplete=function(){scene.add( mesh )}` setting a callback function inside a callback function? Why simply not to put `scene.add(mesh);` instead of it?

Comment: thanks, but I tried that, too. screen stays empty.

Comment: Ah, you said that you published it, thus you got an archive with html, json and js files. App.json is a file of a whole scene. I think you need to do `File -> Export Object`.

Comment: and `File -> Export Scene` if I already applied textures and lights via editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a box, applied `MeshStanardMaterial` with a texture, put directional light there and then I did `File -> Export Scene`. I got a "scene.json" file.

After this in code I loaded the scene with `ObjectLoader`

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( 'scene.json', function(object){
    scene.add(object);
    console.log(scene.children);
});
```

as the result I got a scene with a box and a directional light.

[example](http://west77.ru/content/r81/loadscene.html)

And a small remark, in your example code you don't call `render()` function from `animate()` function.